# Maximum speed of 100% reflective light sails

Tags: technology, space, space-travel, spaceships, solar-sails

So, it’s the 23rd century, and due to the cost of fuel these days, people are exploring new methods of interplanetary travel that does not require reaction mass. Light sails spring to mind.

Modern light sails are pretty slow. Luckily, the magic of nanotechnology now allows for the production of nanotube-based materials that are 99.6% absorbent or reflective of visible light. Using the latter material, how fast could a light-sail craft travel, on sunlight alone, in our solar system?

Comment: You’ll need to provide more information to get an accurate answer. Mass per square meter, melting point, that sort of thing

Comment: You should really do some researches before asking. For my master thesis, at the beginning of the century, I routinely made mirrors with 99.99999% reflectivity without using any nanotube.

Comment: @L.Dutch there's a bit of a gap between the things you might make for an optics bench, and a few hectares of 20nm foil.

Comment: @L.Dutch how much did they weigh? The thinner the glass backing is the harder it is to manufacture.

Answer (score 4):

### TL;DR: 13% c

I'm basing my answer on the 1999 NASA Institute for Advanced Concepts report, [Ultra-Thin Solar Sails for Interstellar Travel: Phase I Final Report](http://www.niac.usra.edu/files/studies/final_report/333Christensen.pdf).

The analysis looks at an aluminum nano-grid mesh rather than carbon nanotubes, but you may be able to extrapolate (or handwave) some of the specs based on their findings.

The acceleration of a solar sail, $a$ `m/s^2`, at some distance from the Sun, $r$ `AU`, can be calculated by

$$a = \frac{2AI}{mc}\frac{1\text{AU}}{r^2}$$

where

- $A$ is area, m^2,
- $m$ is mass, kg,
- $I$ is solar irradiance at 1 AU, 1,360 W/m^2,
- $c$ is the speed of light, 300,000,000 m/s.

The report examines the performance of solar sails by their "characteristic acceleration", $a_c$ `m/s^2`, which is a sail's starting acceleration under 1 AU solar irradiance;

$$a_c = R\frac{P_s}{ρ_a},$$

where

- $R$ is a coefficient of reflectivity (ex.: 0.9),
- $P_s$ is solar radiation pressure at 1 AU, 9.12 µN/m,
- $ρ_a$ is areal density, or sail material density (kg/m^3) times sail thickness (m).

For example, an aluminum nano-grid sail a few nanometers thick may have an $a_c$ of ~0.3 m/s.

A solar sail's terminal velocity (at infinity), $v_{\infty}$ `km/s`, from some starting distance, $r_s$ `AU`, is found by integrating the above equation for solar sail acceleration to infinity. The paper does this with distances, accelerations, and solar irradiance normalized to 1 AU.

$$v_{\infty}\text{,km/s} = 548\sqrt{\frac{a_c}{r_s}}$$

Below is a table of results for increasing characteristic acceleration and decreasing perihelion, or closest approach to the Sun. The final row imagines the performance of a futuristic carbon nanotube sail:

[image: table 1]

---

Carbon nanotubes have a similar heat of vaporization compared to aluminum (355 kJ/mol vs 293 kJ/mol), so, depending on its reflectance, absorbance, and emittance, a carbon nanotube sail's minimum perihelion may not be much closer than an aluminum sail's. There's room to fudge the numbers, though.

> If these perforations were eventually made of carbon nano-structures
> rather than out of a nano-grid of aluminum, accelerations of 10 to 100 m/s^2 may be possible, enabling interstellar travel to α Centauri in less than a century.

Comment: Heat of vaporization doesn't enter into it; a carbon nanotube material might have a melting point >2000K higher than aluminum, and so the aluminum sail will have disintegrated when the carbon one is still going. Quite important for those low perihelion manoevers.